# can i use division when im inducting a proof?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

So I recently started learning Math by myself and I have a question about induction.
So, I was trying to prove $$n^2>n+1$$

the induction step:
$$(n+1)^2>(n+1)+1$$

$$(n+1)(n+1)>(n+1)+1$$

so, I thought that I could divide each side by $(n+1)$

then

$$1+n> 1+ 1/(n+1)$$

Concluding that $1+n$ is bigger cause 1 plus an integer is bigger than 1 plus $1/(n+1)$

however, I'm not sure if it is valid to use division.

Comment: It's fine as long as you know that $n+1 > 0$.

Comment: What is the underlying set? If it's $\mathbb Z$ then when $n=-1$ you can't divide by $n+1$.

Comment: You can definitely use division, but you must add the constraint that in addition to $n$ being an integer, $n$ must also be greater than -1, so that $n+1$ is always greater than $0$, because if $n+1$ was negative, you would have to flip the inequality symbol.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus Presumably it's the natural numbers; the statement isn't true for $n=0$ in any case.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus it's not even true in $\mathbb{Z}$ though

Comment: @mjqxxxx can't be $\mathbb{Z}^+$ either, as it's false also when $n=1$. It holds for all integers greater than or equal to $2$ though

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have to prove it  for all integers n ≥ 2

Comment: Oh thanks, that clarifies a lot

Comment: Now that you have proved that if it holds for $n$ it holds for $n+1$, prove it holds for $n=2$, and your proof is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that you did not use the induction hypothesis.  So what you have done is not a proof by induction.

Comment: why is that? I'm confused

Comment: @A_person see my answer which should explain GEdgar's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, It seems you want to prove this statement: $n^2 > n+1$ for all integers $n \ge 2$. To do this with induction, you would first show this statement is true for $n=2$, (simple enough, 2^2 > 2+1), then show if the statement is true for an integer $n \ge 2$, then it is true for $n+1$.

In the induction step, we **assume** that $n^2 > n+1$ is true, and want to **show** that $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$ is true. In other words, we don't know whether $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$ is true, that is what we need to verify.

So, you must work starting from something you know is true (such as $n \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n \ge 2$) and deduce that $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$ with the assumption that $n^2 > n+1$.

So in your proof, you're working a bit backwards by starting at $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$, which is a normal way to figure out the solution. But your actual solution should be going the other way. So the heart of you question is: Is division logically reversible, and the answer is yes. More precisely, for $c > 0$, $a > b$ if and only if $\frac{a}{c} > \frac{b}{c}$.

Now in fact, you didn't even use induction to prove this, since your argument doesn't use the assumption $n^2 > n+1$. You've written a direct proof that $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$. An inductive proof would look like the following:

Base Case: $2^2 > 2 + 1$ is true

Inductive step: Let $n \ge 2$ and assume that $n^2 > n+1$. Then,

$$ (n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 > (n+1) + 2n + 1 = 3n+2 > (n+1)+1$$

Answer (score 3):

I Don's see a problem with dividing, however, you need to show that $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$ based on the fact that you have assumed that $n^2 > n+1$

I would work one side of $(n+1)^2 > (n+1)+1$ until you showed that the relation holds.

$(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 > (n+1) + 2n+1 = 3n+2 > n+2$ when $n>1 $

Answer (score 2):

As $n\geq 2$, you can indeed divide by $n+1$ there, that's not really a problem. All that remains is to prove the base case, i.e. when $n=2$.

In case you're interested, an alternative argument for the entire problem without induction would be to notice that, as $n\geq 2$,

$$n^2\geq 2n=n+n> n+1.$$